# Why does using an integer value as a 'while' loop condition work in Python?

Tags: python, while-loop, integer, conditional-statements

The following code will output infinite lines of "test".

```
foo = 5
while foo:
    print("bar")
```

The other day I came across an answer here about digit sums. This was the code shown in the answer:

```
def digit_sum(t):
    s = 0
    while t:
        s += t % 10
        t //= 10
    return s
```

The part I'm focusing on is the "while t:" part. How and why does this work?

Comment: 0 is false and non-zero is true.

Comment: Could you explain your question in more detail? Because, as of now, my answer would be something like: "That's just the way it is".

Comment: You could have found the answer by reading the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth

Comment: Partly historical from C (and possibly earlier?) that zero is considered False.    The `bool` class is a subclass of `int`, so they are closely related.  Note that character `"0"` (zero) is True in Python, but False in Perl.

Comment: @cdarke Surely 0 is false in python too, while 1 is true?

Comment: @LauraCookson: integer 0 is false in python, but character "0" is true.

Comment: @cdardke Well fancy that! I'm going to tell that to everyone in my class (school) and blow their minds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `while` condition tests for *truth*. Any non-zero numeric value is considered true. See the [*Truth Value Testing* section](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) in the Python documentation:

> Any object can be tested for truth value, for use in an `if` or `while`
>   condition or as operand of the Boolean operations below. **The following
>   values are considered false:**
>
> - `None`
> - `False`
> - **zero of any numeric type, for example, `0`, `0L`, `0.0`, `0j`.**
> - any empty sequence, for example, `''`, `()`, `[]`.
> - any empty mapping, for example, `{}`.
> - instances of user-defined classes, if the class defines a
>     `__nonzero__()` or `__len__()` method, when that method returns the integer zero or bool value `False`.
>
> **All other values are considered true — so objects of many types are
>   always true.**

Bold emphasis mine.

In your sample `while` loop, `t` trends to 0 (integer division by 10), so eventually `while t:` ends because `t` is considered false.

Comment: Note that `__nonzero__` is Python 2, renamed `__bool__` in Python 3.

Comment: I guess my question was not taken very well, but thanks a lot for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You already got useful answers, but I just wanted to answer your question in a way that can be easily understood by someone who is a beginner in Python.
You could rewrite your code as:

```
def digit_sum(t):
    s = 0
    while t!=0:
        s += t % 10
        t = t//10
    return s
```

'while t' is equivalent to 'while t!=0', meaning that the loop will end when t is equal to 0.

In your for loop, 't //= 10' is equivalent to 't = t // 10' ('//' is a floor division operator and returns an integer). So the value of t becomes smaller each time the loop is executed, until it eventually reaches the value of 0. At this point, the 'while t' condition is False and the loop ends.